# how to encode ÿ using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

Hi I tried thousands of encode, decode for this word L'Haÿ-les-Roses .
Can somebody help me on how to encode correctly a word with ÿ using python 2.7?

```
encode("utf-8")
encode("utf-16")
encode("latin-1")
...
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Why do you want to encode or decode?

Comment: Unicode handling is much nicer in Python 3. In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to do with it? To encode it is simple:

```
a = u"Saint-Rousÿes"
b = a.encode("utf-8")
c = b.decode("utf-8")
print c
# Saint-Rousÿes
```

But I think it depends on your situation. It doesn't matter how you encode it(surely using supported encoding), you just need to use the same encoding to decode it.

## update

I wrote a minimal test:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def test():
    return u"L'Haÿ-les-Roses"

app.run()
```

And I can see `L'Haÿ-les-Roses` without any error when I access `localhost:5000`. So maybe you should make your question more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote in a worg way the word, the correct word is: L'Haÿ-les-Roses, just I want to send it from python to UI using flask. Before of this just i had stressed vocals and was working all well. Now, I have words like this one and it's not working well.

Comment: You can return an unicode string to UI by `return u"L'Haÿ-les-Roses"`

Comment: No is not working, now with unicode, is showing this L&#39;Haÿ-les-Roses and giving an error 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xff' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to put a declaration at the top of your source file indicating how it is supposed to be read?

`# -*- coding:<some encoding> -*-`

I believe in this case you would be looking for

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Yes, I setted it as encoding utf-8